# Can't change directory to network drive

Tags: error, microsoft-windows, working-directory

Our company has recently changed to networked home directories. This includes setting enviroment variables.

This has created the odd situation that gvim thinks my home directory is :

```
:echo $HOME
H:\
```

but I cannot change the current directory to that drive or edit any files there. This also means that my `vimrc` is not loaded.

```
:cd H:\
E344: Can't find directory "H:\" in cdpath
E472: Command failed
```

**Can any one help me get vim to change to H:\ and edit files there?**
I use Windows 7, gvim 7.4

**EDIT**
I tried later CREAM versions 7.4.638 (the latest) and 7.4.099 (closest to 7.4.096 suggested by Christian Brabandt), both had the same error.

**EDIT**

Thanks for suggestions, but none have helped so far.

I can change to `h:\` in the vim.exe file which comes with Git on windows (vim 7.3, 32 bit windows console version, but not any of the gvim versions I have tried.

Comment: Using `:cd F:/` and `:cd F:\ ` (I don't have a `H:`) works for me on Windows 7 with Vim 7.4 with no patches (as downloaded from www.vim.org)... I can't reproduce this problem.... :-/

Comment: I'm having this problem when I launch vim from certain programs, but not when I launch it from the start bar.  Version: 8.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem myself by using [Haroogan vim](https://bitbucket.org/Haroogan). When I cd to h:\ in Haroogan vim it works, and it also successfully runs my vimrc files there.

I guess this was either something strange about my work's network drive and/or a bug in vim that will eventually be resolved. Still, if you have this problem, I would try Haroogan vim.

Comment: link is broken :(

Answer (score 4):

This was a bug, that was fixed in 7.4.096. (You didn't specify exact version, so I assume, you are using plain 7.4 version and I used to have the same problem when cding into a UNC path)

Comment: Answered by the contributor of the [patch](ftp://ftp.vim.org/pub/vim/patches/7.4/7.4.096) himself!

Comment: Is there a way to download a compiled version of 7.4.096 for Windows?

Comment: @ChestertheRooster I believe using the builds from Cream (http://sourceforge.net/projects/cream/files/Vim/) are the way to go.

Comment: Thanks, but I downloaded vim 7.4.638 from the cream link (above), and get same error `E344: Can't find directory "H:\" in cdpath`

Comment: @ChestertheRooster I have a similar setup at work and `:cd H:\\` works fine for me. Are you sure the network drive is mounted?

Comment: @jamessan, yes, h drive is mounted. I can cd to it from cmd.exe, mingw bash shell, even in the vim.exe provided in mingw but not gvim

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try `:cd H:`? Purely guessing based on the contents of `:help dos-:cd` http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/os_dos.html#dos-:cd

Comment: A good suggestions, but same error message.